# ng-route handling outside the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

**Edit - Added a plunkr** http://plnkr.co/edit/euD4FG?p=preview

the RouteController is not getting called, please have a look

<strike>Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smartdev101/tv1p9n4h/</strike>

```
angular.module(this.constructor.NAME, ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    self.config($routeProvider)
})
.controller("RouteController", function($scope, $routeParams){
    self.routeController($scope, $routeParams)})
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("browser"), [this.constructor.NAME]);
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="browser"></div>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#/attendees/3" target="_self">Racu, Cristian</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#/attendees/4" target="_self">Shnider, Brent</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#/attendees/6" target="_self">Suess, Mike</a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: where have you defined your ng-app?

Comment: What's this.constructor?

Comment: no ng-app, I'm manually bootstrapping angular

Comment: this constructor is an initializer provided by the framework and provides the same scope as this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, spell error & missing ng-view. Should be controller in $routeProverder.when, just change your config into this:

```
config: function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/attendees/:param', {
        template:"no template",
        //constroller: "RouteController"
        controller: "RouteController"
    })
},
```

And add ng-view into your html. Seems ngRoute won't work without ng-view

```
<div id="browser">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

[Here is JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/tv1p9n4h/3/)

Comment: good catch :) quick question, is there a way to simplify things, I mean get rid of this div id browser and associated ng-view, I just need the core functionality of $routeProvider, my application logic will handle the rest

Comment: @user2727195 [Get the same issue in angular github.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1580) Seems you cannot use the $routeProvider without ng-view. So I think you can write your own route provider if you don't like angular-route. : )

Comment: It's still not working, can you please check, I've a single file at plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/euD4FG?p=preview

Comment: it works, it was was this stupid popup blocker wasted hours inside chrome